# Swift core data NSFetchRequest predicate to fetch date time

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have a database table called *UVHour* that is the following structure

[image: UVHour]

My app will populate the UVHour table from a JSON that looks like the following

```
[
    {
        "ORDER": 1,
        "DATE_TIME": "SEP/04/2020 04 AM",
        "UV_VALUE": 0
    },
    {
        "ORDER": 2,
        "DATE_TIME": "SEP/04/2020 05 AM",
        "UV_VALUE": 0
    }
]
```

Current NSFetchRequest

```
static var uvIndexNowRequest: NSFetchRequest<UVHour>
    {
        let dateTimeNow = Date()
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMM/d/yyyy hh a"
        let dateHourStr = formatter.string(from: dateTimeNow)
        
        let request: NSFetchRequest = UVHour.fetchRequest()
        
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "order", ascending: true)]

        // Below code will throw 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "date_time == Sep/4/2020 08 PM"
        // request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date_time == \(dateHourStr)")
        
        return request
    }
```

**Question**

How can I write a predicate that will fetch the UVHour with the current date and time matching the current hour?

**Example**

Say that the current date is September 4th, 2020 04:10 AM.

Based on the above JSON I would fetch a UVHour that is the following

```
[
    {
        "ORDER": 1,
        "DATE_TIME": "SEP/04/2020 04 AM",
        "UV_VALUE": 0
    }
]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to update **uvIndexNowRequest** to find my solution. See below code

```
static var uvIndexNowRequest: NSFetchRequest<UVHour>
    {
        let dateTimeNow = Date()
        
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.timeZone = .current
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMM/d/yyyy hh a"
        
        // Find date String from 'formatter.dateFormat'
        let dateHourStr = formatter.string(from: dateTimeNow)
        
        // Get date from dateHourStr
        let someDateTimeOpt = formatter.date(from: dateHourStr)
        
        let request: NSFetchRequest = UVHour.fetchRequest()
        
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "order", ascending: true)]
        
        if let someDate = someDateTimeOpt {
            request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date_time == %@", someDate as CVarArg)
        }
        
        return request
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A shorter alternative is an extension of `NSDate`(!) to get the hour. The benefit is you can use the computed property as a keypath.

```
extension NSDate {
    dynamic var isInCurrentHour : Bool {
        return Calendar.current.isDate(self as Date, equalTo: Date(), toGranularity: .hour)
    }
```

}

---

```
static var uvIndexNowRequest: NSFetchRequest<UVHour>
{
    let request: NSFetchRequest = UVHour.fetchRequest()
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "order", ascending: true)]
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date_time.isInCurrentHour == TRUE")
    
    return request
}
```

Comment: I added your code but got **NSUnknownKeyException** exception with error.."this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key hour"

I think it has something to do with your 

`NSPredicat(format:"date_time.hour== %ld", currentHour)`

Comment: Please try it with `dynamic`

Comment: `dynamic` makes the property *key value coding-compliant*

Comment: Thanks man. I had no idea that I could do it this way!

Comment: Wanted to give you an update. How you are querying core data is no longer throwing me errors, but when I run the fetchRequest I am no longer retrieving the correct data. I'll look more into it, and give you an update.

Comment: I see, please see the edit. It checks if `date_time` is in the current hour rather than comparing only the `hour` components.

Comment: I ran the exact code can got the *NSUnknownKeyException* exception. With message `reason: '[<__NSTaggedDate 0xec1317f7c3bb92da> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key isInCurrentHour.'`